# BigQuery Date Diff

Tags: google-bigquery

Having a lot of trouble working with bigquery and this error message on the code below:

```
No matching signature for function PARSE_DATE for argument types: STRING, TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: PARSE_DATE(STRING, STRING) at [4:5]

DATE_DIFF(
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', created_at), 
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', closed_at), 
    DAY
  ) days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on error message  - `created_at` and `closed_at` are timestamp datatype, so you can use below

```
DATE_DIFF(
    DATE(created_at), 
    DATE(closed_at), 
    DAY
  ) days
```

or just simply

```
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
    created_at, 
    closed_at, 
    DAY
  ) days
```